# how to stop direct access a page without login in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have login page, and after login I have user information related pages. so i don't want to direct access those pages from url. Instead of it will redirect to login page. how can I do that.

my sessions.php page code

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
} 
$login_session=$_SESSION['email'];
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: Set session variable after login and destroy them after logout..make a separate php file which will check if `$_SESSION` is set..If it is set then do nothing else `redirect` to `login.php`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your login page: if user successfully logged-in then set any session variable i.e. `$_SESSION['userLogin'] = "Loggedin";`

**Then**
each and every page check user loggedin or not by below code:

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['userLogin']) || $_SESSION['userLogin'] == ''){
    header("Location: http://example.com/login.php");
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks..If my answer was helpful then accept it by clicking right marker and give up vote. This is the best way to appreciate the answer.